# Whats the most straight frward way to get my Elastic Beansalk instances to join a windows domain?

Tags: amazon-ec2, active-directory, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk app that has some dependencies on a windows domain. What is the best way to get my elastic beanstalk EC2 instances to join the domain?